# Shimano tourney 7 speed shifter for rear not working

Tags: shimano

My bike's shifter for lowering the rear gears is not working. It just slide all the way and "click", "click" sound comes but gear does't shift to lower ones. Its currently stuck at the 7th gear and won't shift. The cable also appears to be a little loose. What should I do? Please help.

Comment: 99 times out of 100, the solution with tourney shifters is to chuck it out and put some other shifter on. But the cable may have just slipped out of the derailleur a bit (My front derailleur is like this, since the bolt doesn't have enough grip). Does the derailleur move if you pull on the cable with your hand?

Answer (score 1):

The cable could have broken, leaving the derailleur sitting on the smallest cog on the upper limit.  I had this a few weeks ago, the cable had broken within the shifter so was not immediately visible.

If when shifting you feel little or no resistance when trying to change to a lower gear this will be a good indicator that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to go to LBS to solve it, as there are several details to consider.
But if you want to do it yourself, here is some advice:
1. Check the cable for rust inside the outers - how smooth does it move inside. If it rust, replace it (the way to do it depends on the shifter you have).
2. Screw almost to end the B screw (this screw have a hole in it's center, and the cable go throw it).
3. At the 9mm screw under the derailleur see how the cable go throw it, then open it.
4. Check that all outers are in their places.
5. Pull the cable as tight as you can and while you continue pull it, tight the 9mm screw.
Then check that all gears are work good - it might desire some adjustment.